# collaborative filtering in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm looking for a solution for collaborative filtering in rails or even possible examples.  So far I have only found acts_as_recommendable which looks useful but I noticed it hasn't had any updates in the last 2 years.

Does anyone know of any other solutions and/or examples?

Comment: After 3 years and 4 answers my question is closed as not constructive?

Answer (score 3):

Have you evaluated [Apache Mahout](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/)? It is a Java based solution, with HTTP access to recommendation engine.

Reference:

[Introducing Mahout](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout/)

Answer (score 2):

This pertains to the examples part of your question, as both the libraries mentioned below are in Java.

The article referenced in above answer, written by Apache Mahout-Taste library author, `has neat examples, source code of the examples( using 2.5GB wikipedia data) , and an excellent packaging to run` and see those examples in action, in a few minutes.

[Apache Mahout-Taste](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout/)

The specific section is `Building a recommendation engine`

Here is another open source recommendation engine.
 [easyrec](http://easyrec.org)

Answer (score 1):

In 2013, there's the [ActiveRecord Reputation System](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/) gem by Twitter. There's also a [free RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

here is a 50 line recommendation system in Ruby: http://www.igvita.com/2007/01/15/svd-recommendation-system-in-ruby/

there is one link there which doesn't work (when he says "mathies click here" it points to Using linear algebra for intelligent information retrieval by Berry et al.: http://www2.denizyuret.com/ref/berry/berry95using.pdf )